# Maximum resolution of 3D printers

Tags: 3d, print-design, resolution

I was looking at 3D printers and I wanted to know the maximum achievable resolution in 3D printers that use the extrusion method (NOT the 3D laser printers).

Some manufacturers claim a 20 Micron resolution, with a 0.4 mm extrusion nozzle. I wonder if there are commercially available printers that can do better than that. 1 micron or maybe something in the nano scale?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with Graphic Design. Are you simply unable to find a manufacturer of these 3D printers? What is specifically wrong with the google results to "3d printer 1 micron"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the technical spesification of 3D printers.

Comment: I've seen many questions considering printing here and that's why I have posted this. Feel free to close it!

Comment: I know a few graphic designers who've worked with 3D printers. It's not mainstream yet, but I wouldn't close a question just because it's about an area on the up. That said, since it's still a fringe area overspilling from product design etc, it's unlikely many people here will have had the chance to do much 3D printing related work. You might get better results elsewhere: a specialist forum, or maybe the techies at http://superuser.com ?

Comment: There's currently a proposal at Area 51 for a [Digital Fabrication](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/59918/digital-fabrication?referrer=DNjkxD5fi1_k_arflz249A2) site. I suggest you support it!

Comment: I completely agree with user568458. Unfortunately I'm not sure how much response it can get here, but I'd definitely encourage you to ask and answer your own questions if you have something you consider is more closely related to GD. We'd love to have some info about 3D printers on the site!

Comment: I am also not against 3D printing questions, but this specific one seems to be only about finding and purchasing one with a specific nozzle. So even with a Product Design background there is not really much I can add.

Comment: ok I promise not to buy it. What is the maximum resolution and the minimum nozzle size that has been reached?

Comment: Using a nozzle necessarily limits how small a bit one can successfully place --- that said, there are people trying nozzles as small as 0.2mm ( http://www.printrbottalk.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=2584 ). There are commercially available printers using stereolithography and inkjet 3D printing which can do much higher resolution than typical FDM machines w/ 0.35--0.5mm nozzles.